# LidarJoin tool only processes 1 file, there is no join

Tags: attribute-joins, las, combine

New user here. I am trying to combine two .Las files into 1. I add the 2 las files into input box but it only outputs 1 of these files.there is no join. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Are you using las merge from LasTools inside QGIS?  CloudCompare, Whiteboxtools, Python Laspy and PDAL aslo work.

Comment: Running it from Whitebox inside Q GIS gave me an error and didn't produce squat so I was running it from the"run" window in WBT. That is where it was just spitting out the first las file and nothing else. I tried LAS Merge tool from inside Q GIS but that was even freaker. In the first box I put in a las file but when I went to add a las file in the second box it prompted me for a laz file and wouldn't take a las file. Ugggg.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried it again with White Box Run application and was successful this time making the join. White Box from inside QGIS still doesn't work and gives me an error message. MergeLAS from LaStools didn't work eather.